# No sound (USB speakers) in Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty Jackalope

Tags: ubuntu, usb, audio, ubuntu-9.04

I just installed Ubuntu 9.04 and have been unable to get sound functioning.  I have a set of USB speakers (not USB powered with a stereo plug... they are totally USB).

I've tried plugging them directly into the tower as well as into the USB port on my Dell 2405FPW monitor.  Both USB ports are functioning correctly (I tested by sticking a flash drive in there - they both read it), and the speakers are functioning correctly in Windows.

If it's relevant, I have an SB Audigy 2 sound card that came with the computer, but is not being used.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** These are the speakers - [Logitech S-150 USB Speakers](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/business/products/speakers_audio/devices/3757&cl=gb,en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to assign sound output to them with PulseAudio.  There's a WIKI about configuring PulseAudio [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio), but it comes down to just a couple of steps:
1. Install pavucontrol, the PulseAudio volume control panel, and launch it.  Switch to the playback tab.
2. Launch something that plays sound (like Totem).  It should show the VU meter for the playback.
3. Right click on the VU meter and choose "Move Stream... >"  You should be able to select your USB stuff if HAL detected it properly.

Good Luck!

Comment: That seemed to do the trick... thanks a lot!  I would up-vote, but I do not have enough rep yet.  Only one issue though... I noticed that I wasn't hearing the login/logout sounds or things of that nature.  Any idea what that could be?

Comment: Quite possibly system sounds are not going through PulseAudio, or are but are still getting routed to your internal soundcard.